# jQuery Delegate - Find Delegate Object Inside Event Closure

Tags: jquery, delegates

How can I access a delegated object inside a delegate event handler? Hopefully an example should clarify my vague question.

```
$parent.delegate('a.some_class', 'click', someHandler);

function someHandler(e) {
  //how do I find $parent here?
}
```

This is partly down to how I've structured my particular .js file, where declarations are separate from implementation (yeah, old skool I know).

In someHandler, e.target and $(this) refer to the a.some_class object. Does e also have a reference to $parent? If not, what is the recommended way of finding the $parent?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: There *is* a way to grab the original element - `e.originalEvent.currentTarget`:

```
$parent.delegate('a.some_class', 'click', someHandler);

function someHandler(e) {
  var originalParent = $(e.originalEvent.currentTarget);
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/pjHQ6/

---

Original answer:

I'd probably do it like this:

```
$parent.delegate('a.some_class', 'click', someHandler);
function someHandler(e) {
  var parent = $(this).parent();

  // Or if $parent isn't the immediate ancestor of the links:
  var parent = $(this).closest('.parentClass');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input put the parent class or position is not known at runtime as this particular .js is initialized by multiple objects.

Comment: I was just looking at this in IE7 because `e.originalEvent.currentTarget` is `undefined` in my case -- but `e.delegateTarget` **is** what I need.  Strange because otherwise it works "everywhere else".

Answer (score 2):

Stupid me. Should have read the jQuery docs better.

This should do it:

```
$parent.delegate('a.some_class', 'click', $parent, someHandler);

function someHandler(e) {
  var parent = e.data;
}
```

e.data (in SomeHandler) always points to eventData, if using this delegate call.

```
.delegate( selector, eventType, eventData, handler )
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Jens Roland is correct.
To add, the e.currentTarget should have given you the $parent where the event is actually handled.
There's a bug that explains why currentTarget is not working the way it's supposed to
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11756